# Content is blinking when resizing layout at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very complex `ListView` element. When user scrolls down (to the 5-th element, for example) I hide `ActionBar` (via `hide()` method) to provide more space for `ListView`. It looks like when I do so, android framework calles something like `redraw` method to scale content of ListView to the larger space. And this scaling happens at runtime without any build-in animation. Moreover, for complex layouts (like mine) redrawing provides ugly blinking effect for views, which changed own positions or sizes. It seems that this behavior makes any dynamic layout changing unusable in most cases. Does anybody has any ideas how to solve this problem? May be are there tricky ways to provide animation for such redrawing?

P.S. I've just tried `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`, but with no effect. Views appears much smoother, but blinks are still here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get rid of the action bar, you now have more visible space to draw.  This causes the framework to resize all the views in your Activity.  This is the same thing that happens when you change the visibility of any view from VISIBLE to GONE (changing it to INVISIBLE will not cause a redraw, because the space is still reserved).

To avoid this-  from the documentation on ActionBar.show()

"

Show the ActionBar if it is not currently showing. If the window hosting the ActionBar does not have the feature FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY it will resize application content to fit the new space available.
"

So you need to specify that feature.  You may then need to tweak your view so that the action bar doesn't overlay anything that you want shown.

Comment: Thank you, @Gabe Sechan, it looks like working solution (but can be applied only for ActionBar, of course).

Answer (score 0):

check this solution May be help to you

you also need to set the cache color hint to black in xml of `Listview`

```
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that may fit in your requirements is to have one custom Header view instead of action-bar, Add this header view as List Header and it will scroll with list & will use screen space more efficiently.